# Errors on new version of SystemJS - Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, module, commonjs

I'm learning typescript so I created 2 classes: main and sub. Sub is imported into main and main tries to use a method in sub. But when I run it, I got the error: "**Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined**". I searched and found what the problem was. However, it seems to work perfectly with the older version of SystemJS. Could you anyone please explain to me what changed in SystemJS that caused the issue?

System.defaultJSExtensions = true; seems also doesn't work with the latest version.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "dist",
    },
    "exclude": [
        "dist",
        "js",
    ]
}
```

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <!-- SystemJS v0.19.31 -->
    <!-- <script src="js/system.js"></script> -->

    <!-- SystemJS 6.4.1 -->
    <script src="js/system.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        System.defaultJSExtensions = true;
        System.import('./dist/main');
    </script>
</body>
```

**main.ts**

```
import { Sub } from "./sub";

let s = new Sub();
s.printSomething();
console.log("abc");
```

**sub.ts**

```
export class Sub {
    printSomething() {
        console.log({
            name: "data",
            category: "test"
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `"module": "system"`

Comment: @AluanHaddad it doesn't work :(